# grails export plugin - add new column to the existing file

Tags: grails, export-to-csv

Hi I am trying to use [grails export plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/export), as far the `plugin` is working great to export domain classes in `csv` file, but I having a new requirement of adding an additional column to the existing `csv` file, as far the [documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/export) is there is no details about this new requirement. Is it possible? Any suggestions...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "existing csv"? Is this an actual pre existing CSV file or do you just want to add another column to the ouput CSV when you use the export plugin?

Comment: @ Joshua Moore, I am getting the file from my local system which contain lots of data, at the end each row I like to write the status after processing that particular row

Comment: The export plugin isn't going to be useful in this case then. What you need to investigate is using some type of CSV reader (opencsv for example) if the file is small enough to work within in memory or spring batch if you need something that can process large files efficiently.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, I guess using opencsv also it is not possible, might be, have to create a new file is the only solution

Comment: Yes you will have to create a new file using a CSV reader such as opencsv or supercsv.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore, yes we decided to go like that only, thank u for your time